# How can I optionally include an external library?

Tags: c#, dll, portable-class-library

I have a PCL that I want to contain a bunch of base classes, so I do not have to make them again for each project. Now I am contemplating adding in Facebook, as I will have to reference an external dll each time I want to use my PCL in a project, even if it's a project with only a few screens, because I would have build errors if I don't.

For those saying that's not an issue: I am planning on adding even more external dll's that I don't need every time.

How can I solve this? I want to include the code to use this dll in my PCL, but I don't want to be forced to include the dll each time I use the PCL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you probably want to use types from the external library in your code, and you *can't* do that without referencing the library.

A way around this problem is by using reflection, but your code will become much more complex and you wish you didn't.

Another solution is to:

- Create an interface for each external dependency in your "common PCL" (ie. `ISocialMediaPlatform` for the facebook).
- Create a new PCL for each external dependency, that references both your "common PCL" and the external library, and has a class that implements one of these interfaces (ie. `FacebookSocialMediaPlatform : ISocialMediaPlatform`)

  - This implementation can then reference the external dependency and use its types directly
- Inject the implementation of each interface into your "common PCL" using reflection or a Dependency Injection framework

This does add another layer of complexity, but as a side effect it also makes your common PCL code testable.

Finally, the solution I personally would prefer, is to not have a huge "common PCL" at all, but to split it into a few smaller ones that fulfill one specific role.

Comment: Well my issue is that I have about 20 libraries that I want to optionally include, and more to come in the future. These libraries only need to be referenced once in a "setup" method that gets called from the platform, usually with an app or API key that is abstract or virtual in the "application" class. So I don't see how I can make new PCLs for each of these platforms and pair them up with the right API keys. I was also thinking about linking, where I add annotations if I need them or not (if that even works that way), could you add a solution that uses the linker?

Comment: I can only advise you to keep things small and simple, I don't want to put effort into helping you create what I'd consider an unmaintainable monster library. That's just my opinion though, no offense intended.